# Count Like Description column and sum based on equipment

Tags: sql-server, count, sql-like

In SQL Server, I am trying to group equipment and then count the 'like' Descriptions to get the occurrences. Has anyone done anything like that?

```
Select 
    Equip, Count like Description, 
from
    WorkOrder (nolock) 
where 
    DateTm Between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) and DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1)
Group by 
    Equip, Description 
order by 
    Equip Asc
```

Comment: What is *the 'like' Descriptions*? Sample data and expected results would help, as well as a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Description is a separate column with text typed in by a operator.

Comment: Equip: Machine 1 , Description "part was stuck", Equip: Machine 1, Description "Stuck part". Examples of two operators putting in different data. I want to count both of those as occurrences. Equip: Machine 1 Had 2 occurrences for  a Stuck part.

Comment: Do you want the output should like `[Eq1, part was stuck, 10],[Eq1, test, 2]`

Comment: yes Description and the occurrence count

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: you might be able to get close to what you want using `SOUNDEX()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I am not for sure on SOUNDEX()

Answer (score 0):

This should work. If you want to search with list of descriptions, then add the where class with description like.

```
    Select Equip,Description, count(*) as Count, 
                from WorkOrder (nolock) 
    where DateTm Between DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) and 
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1)
                Group by Equip,Description order by Equip Asc
```

Comment: that seems close but I am wanting to group the description that are 'like' the same

Comment: add where clause. `WHERE Description like '%part was struck%' OR description like '%Struck part%'

Comment: I am wanting it to be dynamic, I don't want to put a description in there. It could be different for different pieces of equipment. If there is a way to do that.

Comment: Description like '%%' well that work? if I leave it blank

Comment: If the Description are close to the same I want to count that as 2 occurrences for that one piece of equipment. If a few words are close to the same

Comment: You can create a new column using CASE statement with descriptions that are close enough to group it. Use the new column in group by to count the occurences

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is to get those with same `description` per `Equip`. You can `group by` and `having` clause for this requirement.

```
select description
    , Equip
    , count(Equip) 
from WorkOrder (nolock) 
where DateTm Between dateadd(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0) 
    and dateadd(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getDate()), -1)
group by description, Equip 
having count(description) > 1
```

Comment: that does show the data but if the words in the description are close than it counts it as a separate occurrence

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte 
 AS (SELECT equip, 
            description, 
            CASE 
              WHEN description LIKE '%part was struck%' 
                    OR description LIKE '%Struck part%' THEN 'STRUCK PART' 
              WHEN description LIKE '%FAILURE%' THEN 'FAILURE' 
              ELSE 'RANDOM' 
            END AS DESCRIPTION_GROUP 
     FROM   workorder (nolock) 
     WHERE  datetm BETWEEN Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0, Getdate()), 0) 
                           AND 
                                   Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, -1, 
                                                  Getdate()), 
                                   -1 
                                   )) 
SELECT equip, 
       description_group, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   cte 
GROUP  BY equip, 
          description_group 
ORDER  BY equip ASC
```

Comment: I got a error when running this, (A result set was generated for update)

Comment: Is there another way to go about it?

Comment: When you are getting the error? Did you execute the query in database and test?

Comment: yes, I tried it in my query browser. I am working in a different software where the case function doesn't work